# Losing data in LoginView after binding parent Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, repeater

I'm having some trouble with a LoginView that is nested inside a Repeater in my ASP.NET 4.5 site. The data gets properly bound when the page loads. But if some external event rebinds the repeater, the content inside the LoginView templates doesn't rebind. I've simplified my code down about as much as I can to make it repeatable. Run this page, then click the Rebind Data button. The button labels disappear. How do I get those to properly rebind (ex: show the Text of the data item that it's bound to)? I would think that calling `DataBind()` on the repeater would rebind all child controls, but I guess not. I tried a couple different iterations of manually binding (and none worked), but would prefer a clean implementation.

RepeaterTest.aspx

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MyNamespace" %>

<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="MyRepeater">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LoginView runat="server">
            <LoggedInTemplate>
                 <asp:Button runat="server" Text='<%# ((Container.Parent as RepeaterItem).DataItem as TestClass).Text %>' /><br />
            </LoggedInTemplate>
            <AnonymousTemplate>
                <asp:Button runat="server" Text='<%# ((Container.Parent as RepeaterItem).DataItem as TestClass).Text %>' /><br />
            </AnonymousTemplate>
        </asp:LoginView>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Rebind Data" OnClick="Unnamed_Click" />
```

RepeaterTest.aspx.cs

```
namespace MyNamespace
    {
    public partial class RepeaterTest : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
        List<TestClass> list = new List<TestClass>()
                {
                new TestClass("hi"),
                new TestClass("hello"),
                new TestClass("bonjour"),
                new TestClass("hola")
                };

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            if (!IsPostBack)
                {               
                MyRepeater.DataSource = list;
                MyRepeater.DataBind();
                }
            }

        protected void Unnamed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            MyRepeater.DataSource = list;
            MyRepeater.DataBind();
            }
        }
    public class TestClass
        {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public TestClass(string text)
            {
            Text = text;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi mason, I failed to reproduce your scenario. For me the labels stay as they are after clicking the button. It's a new ASP .NET 4.5 Web forms project in VS 2013. I also tried to change labels after postback, by instantiating new list collection with diff texts, this works also. Try to check for client side errors, something tampering the viewstate, try to turn off browser link in VS 2013 if applicable..

Comment: I tried the code you have added in your question, I did not have trouble with databinding after clicking on the button outside of the Repeater control. I doubt that you are loosing data in the datasource when you click the button outside of the Repeater control in your actual code. Can you please share the actual code where you are facing this problem?

Comment: This happens because the components are being build after Page_Init. You should go and read about ASP.NET Page Life Cycle. See this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx

The solution is try to build the controls on Page_Init

Comment: @MarcoAlves I'm not building the controls in any event, they're declared in markup.

Comment: @mason I know that. But, trust me, they are being bound after page init. And THIS is your problem. Take a look at the link i've sent to u.